# Item deleted from database but still appearing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to  make my application thread safe, so I have:

```
companyManagment.deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire(questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id);



@Override
@Transactional
public synchronized void deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire(Long questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id) {
    String methodname = " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire ";
    logger.info(methodname      + " questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id["+ (questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id!=null?questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id.toString():null) +"]");
    QuestionsAssignedToQuestionnaires questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase = getQuestionsAssignedToQuestionnaires(questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id);
    if(questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase != null) {
        logger.info(methodname      + " questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase != null");
        questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesRepository.delete(questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id);
    } else {
        logger.info(methodname      + " questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase == null");          
    }
}
```

I have Mysql on my local server. When 2 requests sent to the server, I put a break point on the fist line in the deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire() method. The problem is that JPA does not see that the row has been deleted.

I'm using a link to pass up the information I want to delete so it's easy for me to click that a few times. Could this be the problem?

Anyway, I have the logs:

```
2016-01-10 10:44:19.667  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-8  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id[56]
2016-01-10 10:44:19.669  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-8  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase != null
2016-01-10 10:44:19.688  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-5  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id[56]
2016-01-10 10:44:19.689  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-5  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase != null
2016-01-10 10:44:19.691  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-4  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id[56]
2016-01-10 10:44:19.697  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-4  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase != null
2016-01-10 10:44:19.735  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-3  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questions_assigned_to_questionnaires_id[56]
2016-01-10 10:44:19.764  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-01-10 10:44:19.811  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tAssignedQuestionsToQuestionnaireWrapper : Removing QuestionDraw[3] from mapAllQuestionDrawsForCompany
2016-01-10 10:44:19.812  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-01-10 10:44:19.839  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] data.service.CompanyManagmentImpl        :  http-nio-8080-exec-3  deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire  questionsAssignedToQuestionnairesInDatabase != null
2016-01-10 10:44:19.846  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tAssignedQuestionsToQuestionnaireWrapper : Removing QuestionYesNo[5] from mapAllQuestionYesNosForCompany
2016-01-10 10:44:19.860  INFO 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-01-10 10:44:19.889 ERROR 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.ObjectOpt
imisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected:
 1] with root cause

org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.deleteQuestionToQuestionnaire(Unknown Source)
        at controler.CompanyAdminController.assignQuestionsToQuestionnaire(CompanyAdminController.java:1478)
        at controler.CompanyAdminController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b1a0a1d2.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
        at controler.CompanyAdminController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e616d1e.assignQuestionsToQuestionnaire(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2016-01-10 10:44:19.894 ERROR 9880 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.ObjectOpt
imisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected:
 1] with root cause
```

Comment: If your repository operations are performed in a `@Transactional` way, you shouldn't need to worry about transaction commiting to the DB. Which DB are you using? I still don't understand why you're using a `synchronized` block into your class (which it looks as if it was a `@Service`). Just perform your operations in logic methods and don't mess up with class fields.

Comment: I have this running on a local machine and the database is connected to a remove server, What happens is when I press the submit a few times, it'll go into this code a few times. I need to check to see if the row was deleted before I go ahead and delete it, that's the reason for the synhronized. It's connected to a MySQL database.

Comment: MySql will then delete the row only once, the first transaction which is executed. All the rest of transactions requested after that will end up in an error cause the deleted row won't exist anymore. Your problem seems to be related with latency then. I encourage you not to write a `synchronized` block for that, just don't allow the user clicking the submit button once an again.

Comment: Cool, I'll implement your suggestion. Thanks for your help Xtreme

Comment: Hey, I uploaded to the live server and it's still happening. How do I force the JPA to look into the database rather than looking in the cache, is that possible?

Comment: It depends in your JPA impl and how you've got it configured. Do you have any second level cache configured for your JPA provider? Are the deletion and the `find` executing in the same transaction? Hibernate for example comes with a first level cache implementation only, which shouldn't put you in such a kind of situation.

Comment: To be honest, I'm using this straight out of the box with Spring boot. The checking for row and deleting are not done in the same transaction so I'll try that.

Comment: So strange, cause Spring boot out of the box configuration shouldn't lead you to this behaviour, even more in different transactions. Try it bringing your database to local.

Comment: I updated the question with the new method. The only thing that I'm doing funny is that I'm using a link to pass the values to the get method in the controller. I know, bad way but should that affect how JPA works?

Comment: From the logs, it looks like the synchronized part is not working. I mean it printed out object != null 4 times before it tried to delete.

Comment: Unless, every time I call the link, it creates a new instance.